# Transform many numerical variables to dummy variables at once

Tags: r, transformation, dummy-variable

I'm stuck trying to convert a bunch of integer variables (with values from one to 10, plus a few NAs) into the same number of boolean variables, where values<=8 become FALSE, >8 become TRUE, and NAs remain as NAs.

Based on other Q&As around, I tried the following but nothing worked:

```
TPS <- names(datos[,1:3])
    for(i in TPS) {
     data4[[i]]==NA <- NA
     data4[[i]]<8 <- FALSE
     data4[[i]]>=8 <- TRUE
    }

    TPS <- names(data4[,8:48])
    for(i in TPS) {
      data4[,i]==NA <- NA
      data4[,i]<8 <- FALSE
      data4[,i]>=8 <- TRUE
    }

    TPS <- names(data4[,8:48])
    for(i in TPS) {
      ifelse(data4[,i]<8, FALSE, TRUE)
    }
```

I know how to do it one variable at a time, but my dataset have 64 variables I have to transform in just 2 different ways, so a procedure to do this in just 2 steps would be extremely useful.

Comment: Have you tried `data4[,8:48] >8`

Comment: Please `dput` a sample of data4

Comment: Just tried "data4[,8:48]<8<-FALSE based on akrun's suggestion, but it returns an error message: "incorrect number of arguments to "<<-"

Comment: If it is a normal dataset with numeric columns, it should work.  My code was just `data4[,8:48] >8` and not `data4[,8:48] <8 <- FALSE`.  The output would be a logical matrix of TRUE, FALSE, and NA.  So, you don't need to assign to FALSE again.

Comment: ok, now I got it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use

```
 data4[,8:48] >8
```

The output will be a logical `matrix` of `TRUE/FALSE` values and `NA` (if there are).